# Is there a way pull a new calculation based off multiple criteria being met into the SELECT statement as column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a calculation and setting that as a new column name if certain criteria is met. The criteria would be if Margin_using_List_Price is between .20 and .35 and the Margin_using_MSLP is between 0 and .10, then do List Price multiplied by .90 and rename that as QDP_Tier_1; which works as how I would like it. However I am trying to see if I can add in another field where if Margin_using_List_Price is between .36 and .60 and the Margin_using_MSLP is between .11 and .20, then do List Price multiplied by .80 and rename that as QDP_Tier_2 within the same SELECT statement?

I have tried using a 'case when', but that gave me and error message of "An expression on non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected" Which is the part that is commanded out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is the following code that I have written:

```
SELECT 
       [Country_IBS]
      ,[Item_Number]
      ,List_Price * .90 AS QDP_Tier_1
      ,List_Price * .80 AS QDP_Tier_2
      ,MSLP 
      ,List_Price
      ,Standard_Cost
      ,Margin_using_MSLP
      ,Margin_using_List_Price

FROM #temp

WHERE 
--List_Price * (CASE WHEN Margin_using_List_Price BETWEEN '.40' AND '.60' THEN .80 ELSE 1 END)

Margin_using_List_Price BETWEEN '.20' AND '.35'
AND Margin_using_MSLP BETWEEN '0' AND '.10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Will probably need a little more refining, but there's no reason you couldn't have a CASE in the select

```
SELECT 
  [Country_IBS],
  [Item_Number],
  CASE WHEN ((Margin_using_List_Price BETWEEN '.20' AND '.35') AND (Margin_using_MSLP BETWEEN '0' AND '.10')) THEN List_Price * .90 ELSE 0 END AS QDP_Tier_1,
  CASE WHEN ((Margin_using_List_Price BETWEEN '.36' AND '.60') AND (Margin_using_MSLP BETWEEN '0.11' AND '.2')) THEN List_Price * .80 ELSE 0 END AS QDP_Tier_2,
  MSLP ,
  List_Price,
  Standard_Cost,
  Margin_using_MSLP,
  Margin_using_List_Price
FROM #temp
```